# Check if an object property is optional

Tags: typescript

I have the following class, for example:

```
export class User {
  public name: string | null;
  public birthDate: Date;
}
```

How can I check, for example, in a component, if `name` is an optional property? I can get its type (string) but I can't get any information regardless if it can be nullable or not.

Comment: To what end? None of that information is available at runtime.

Comment: I need to build a query in string format that is going to be different if a property can be nullable or not

Comment: That sounds like it's going to be at runtime, when none of the type information exists. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Yes, at runtime. So you are saying that there isn't a way I can check this?

Comment: Correct. TypeScript is purely at compile-time; once you're running it you're in JavaScript and there is no type information. See e.g. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20birthDate%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A.

Comment: I can get the property type with typeof

Comment: That tells you what the type of the **current value** of the property is, *not* what TypeScript would have enforced at compile time.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Can you add an example how would you use it?

Comment: @PedroNeto You might want to look into using something like [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) for runtime types.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
type IsOptional<T, TypeIfTrue, TypeIfFalse> = undefined extends T
  ? TypeIfTrue
  : TypeIfFalse;

type IsNullable<T, TypeIfTrue, TypeIfFalse> = null extends T
  ? TypeIfTrue
  : TypeIfFalse;

type IsUserNameOptional = IsOptional<User["name"], true, false>;
type IsUserNameNullable = IsNullable<User["name"], true, false>;
```